# maven on windows with remote repository and pscp does not work

Tags: maven

We have a remote repository on a linux server. When I work on a linux machine I dont have any problem to access the repository with scp. I would like to work now on a windows machine on the project but I can't get the remote repository to work.

I followed these instructions: http://ekawas.blogspot.com/2007/02/maven-windows-and-deploying-to-remote.html

I have this in my settings.xml

```
<servers>
<server>
  <id>ssh-repository</id>
  <username>username</username>
  <password>password</password>
  <privateKey>C:\Dev\programs\ssh_private_key.ppk</privateKey>
  <configuration>
    <sshExecutable>plink</sshExecutable>
    <scpExecutable>pscp</scpExecutable>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

```
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>defaultProfile</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>ssh-repository</id>
          <name>SSH-Repository</name>
          <url>scpexe://host:/path-to-rep</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

When I just make pscp on the command prompt, I don't have any problems.
When I try mvn package or mvn clean, it gives the following error:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not transfer artifact .... from/ro ssh-repository ...
```

Is there something wrong with my settings.xml ?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the site or release/snapshots to the repository ?

Comment: I'm just trying to make a package. mvn package or mvn install. But maven can not download the needed dependencies from our remote repository.

Comment: So you are talking about usual dependencies etc.

Comment: Kind of. The project has a dependency on an other project which is in the remote repository on the linux server. Somehow maven can not download this dependency from the remote repository. But I don't find the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if someone has the same problem. I managed to connect to my ssh repository from my windows machine with winscp.

here are the steps

1. install winscp
2. connect to your host with winscp
3. set settings of winscp -> memory -> save configuration in ini file
4. add ssh-rsa keys to know_hosts file > username.ssh\known_hosts
5. edit settings.xml in \username.m2\settings.xml

   - dont use sshExecutable and scpExecutable
   - use scp://hostname/location/to/repo

Answer (score 0):

The best recommendation i can give is to use a repository manager like [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org) or [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) (alphabetical order). That will make you build running indepandant of the platform you are running. Furthermore it will make the configuration of the settings simpler.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Unfortunately I can not change the Server at the moment. A Webdav directory as Maven Repository would also do the trick for me. But until it's done by our Sysadmins, I have to work with the ssh solution. Unfortunately I can't get the connection on my windows machine.